# Spring-ws error on interceptor

Tags: spring, web-services, xsd

I have an issued on my spring-ws-servlet.xml

when i start the ws i receive this error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ws:interceptors'.
```

this is the line with error (spring-ws-servlet.xml):

```
<ws:interceptors><bean class="com.nin.fi.sw.schema.WSLoggingInterceptor"/></ws:interceptors>
```

And this is the header of these file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-1.5.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
```

Libs:
[image]

I tried to attach differentes .xsd but withoud any success.
I dont know what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a schema location for `web-services`

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
```

Comment: My fault, sorry. Im doing wrong copy/paste.The error still happends.

Comment: @user1750751 Do you have the Spring web service jar on your classpath?

Comment: @user1750751 Please show us your libs (maybe with maven?). Also, edit you answer to add the schema location for `web-services`.

Comment: @user1750751 You have version 1.5.9. Use the `xml` namespace schema location `1.5` instead of `2.0`.

Comment: Yes, I have 1.5.9 spring-ws version. I put http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-1.5.xsd in xsi:schemalocation but nothing happened.

Comment: @user1750751 I don't know if it's a copy-paste error in your question, but the `xsd` should go in the `schemaLocation` as it appears in my answer. The `xmlns` declaration should simply be `xmlns:ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"`

Comment: Okey, i edited the post with your response. Thats I have know in my spring-ws-servlet.xml

Comment: @user1750751 Upgrade to 2.0, 1.5 doesn't have `interceptors` element.